# Construction in Topology about an counterexample

Tags: general-topology

> Let a compact subset $K$ of open set $U$ in $(X, \tau)$ a space topology, so it necessary that there exists compact $S$ so that $K \subset \mathbf{int}(S) \subset S \subset U$?

---

I know that if I want disprove that, so I need to find a $X$, $U$ and $K$ such that $S$ there's not exists. But, how can I construct $S$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, such compact $S$ need not exist. Take any space that is not a locally compact and take any point $p$ that has no neighborhood whose closure is compact. Take $K=\{p\}$.

Or, to be specific, let $X=\mathbb Q$ (the rational numbers) with the  usual topology, and let $K$ be any nonempty compact subset (e.g., a singleton, a finite set, a converging sequence, or something more complicated). There is no non-empty open set $V$ such that the closure of $V$ is compact. In particular, given any open $U$ containing $K$ there is no compact $S$ such that $K \subset \mathbf{int}(S) \subset S \subset U.$

Comment: Oh, I didn't see that. Thank you so much! :-)

Comment: Thank you, you are welcome!